# Got a Error when using DataFrame.schema.fields.update

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to cast two columns in my DataFrame. Here is my code:

```scala
val session = SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("UDTransform").getOrCreate()
var df: DataFrame = session.createDataFrame(Seq((1, "Spark", 111), (2, "Storm", 112), (3, "Hadoop", 113), (4, "Kafka", 114), (5, "Flume", 115), (6, "Hbase", 116)))
  .toDF("CID", "Name", "STD")
df.printSchema()
df.schema.fields.update(0, StructField("CID", StringType))
df.schema.fields.update(2, StructField("STD", StringType))
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

I get these logs from my console:

```
   root
 |-- CID: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- STD: integer (nullable = false)

root
 |-- CID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- STD: string (nullable = true)

17/06/28 12:44:32 ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 36, Column 31: A method named "toString" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
```

All I want to know is why this ERROR happen and how can I solve it?
appreciate that very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can not update the schema of dataframe since the dataframe are immutable,
But you can update the schema of dataframe and assign to a new Dataframe.

Here is how you can do

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("CID", col("CID").cast("string"))
.withColumn("STD", col("STD").cast("string"))

newDF.printSchema()
```

The schema of newDF is

```
    root
     |-- CID: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
     |-- STD: string (nullable = true)
```

Your code:

```
df.schema.fields.update(0, StructField("CID", StringType))
df.schema.fields.update(2, StructField("STD", StringType))
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

In your code

`df.schema.fields` returns a `Array` of `StructFields` as

```
Array[StructFields]
```

then if you try to update as

```
df.schema.fields.update(0, StructField("CID", StringType))
```

This updates the value of `Array[StructField]` in `0th` position, I this is not what you wanted

`DataFrame.schema.fields.update` does not update the dataframe schema rather it updates the array of StructField returned by `DataFrame.schema.fields`

Hope this helps

Comment: yes ,it work.But I still want to know why this Error happen.And how to correctly using the API  DataFrame.schema.fields.update??

Comment: DataFrame.schema.fields.update doesnot updates the dataframe schema it rather returns an array and updates the array.