# apache spark 2.2 no toString method available

Tags: apache-spark

While fetching head of a data set i get an error saying:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 60, Column 32: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 60, Column 32: A method named "toString" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
```

I am doing a simple join in the code and then trying to get the head:

```
Dataset<Transaction> ds = getSparkSession().read().text(file).map(Row::mkString, Encoders.STRING())                            
                        .map(row -> {
                            return Transaction.builder()
                                    .account(row.substring(7, 19).trim())                                  
                                    .referenceNumber(row.substring(58, 69).trim())
                                    .dateAndTime(row.substring(71, 79).trim())
                                    .amount(row.substring(87, 100).trim())                                    
                                    .merchantCity(row.substring(160, 173).trim())
                                    .merchantCountry(row.substring(173, 175).trim())                                    
                                    .build();
                        }, Encoders.bean(CreditCardTransaction.class)));

Dataset<User> userDs = getUserDs();

Dataset<FilteredTransaction> fds = ds.filter(functions.length(ds.col("account")).geq("16"))
                        .join(userDs, ds.col("referenceNumber").startsWith(userDs.col("referenceNumber")))                      
                        .select(userDs.col("userId"),
                                ds.col("amount"),
                                ds.col("dateAndTime").cast(DataTypes.TimestampType),
                                ds.col("account"),
                                ds.col("merchantCity"),
                                ds.col("merchantCountry"))
                        .as(Encoders.bean(FilteredTransaction.class))
        );

fds.head(1);
```

When i looked into the generated code i saw it is doing toString on long primitive on line 60 below, is it a Bug?

```
/* 050 */     boolean isNull21 = i.isNullAt(2);
/* 051 */     long value21 = isNull21 ? -1L : (i.getLong(2));
/* 052 */     boolean isNull20 = true;
/* 053 */     java.lang.String value20 = null;
/* 054 */     if (!isNull21) {
/* 055 */
/* 056 */       isNull20 = false;
/* 057 */       if (!isNull20) {
/* 058 */
/* 059 */         Object funcResult9 = null;
/* 060 */         funcResult9 = value21.toString();
```

Comment: please show more of your code. Maybe you are doing something like in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793864/got-a-error-when-using-dataframe-schema-fields-update

Comment: Updated with the code i use to join two datsets.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be mismatching of one of `Dataset` column data type with corresponding field data type in `Encoder` bean class.

Eg, `FilteredTransaction` has type `String` for field `account`. And in the source text file it is a number (will be handled as long). In such case it could not convert `long` to `String` as long does not have `toString` method. So make the same data type (as in inferred Dataset schema) for the field in Encoder bean.

```
class FilteredTransaction {
    ...
    private long account;
    ....
}
```